# Is there a way to call a layout from one fragment to a different one?

Tags: android

Part of my app requires me to be able to transfer a `LinearLayout` from one fragment to another.

Right now this is what I have in the `MainActivity`

```
public ArrayList<LinearLayout> content = new ArrayList<>();
public void addContent(LinearLayout ll)
    {
        content.add(ll);
    }
    public void removeContent(LinearLayout ll)
    {
        content.remove(ll);
    }
    public ArrayList getList()
    {
        return content;
    }
```

Here's what I have in the fragment containing the `LinearLayout`

```
final LinearLayout llWhatBonding = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.llWhatBonding);
        CheckBox checkBox1 = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        TextView tvWhatBonding = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvWhatBonding);
        final ScrollView svWhatBonding = (ScrollView)view.findViewById(R.id.svWhatBonding) ;
        tvWhatBonding.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                svWhatBonding.setVisibility((svWhatBonding.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        checkBox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if(content.contains(llWhatBonding)){
                    object.removeContent(llWhatBonding);
                }
                else{
                    object.addContent(llWhatBonding);
                }
            }
        });
```

And here's what I have in the fragment I want to move the LinearLayout into.

```
    MainActivity object;
    ListView l;
    ArrayAdapter<LinearLayout> adapter;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.start_screen_layout, container, false);
        object = (MainActivity)getActivity();
        TextView tvtest = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvtest);
        tvtest.setText(""+object.getList().size());
        l = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        if(l != null)
        {
            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<LinearLayout>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, object.getList());
            l.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
        return view;
    }
```

I'm using a `ListView` to display each `LinearLayout`.

Right now this is what is showing up

[image: Right now this is what is showing up]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you getting only one in display?. How many layout you have added? Also You can expect to display the layouts you have added into list. Array adapter always use the same layout for each list item.

Comment: Oh no sorry for debugging purposes I put the number there to show how many layouts are in the ListView